# AngularJS dropdown out of sync in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selectlist

I have a problem that only happens in IE. There are a couple dropdown boxes on my form that are populated via WebAPI. That works. But when I click the dropdown arrow and select an item, the first item in the list is the one that is shown. But then when I click another angular control anywhere on the form, the selected value in the dropdown list is updated correctly. Note that I don't actually touch this dropdown box, it's just that AngularJS updates the value to the correct item as long as I 'touch' another AngularJS control. It's as if the $scope has a delay and doesn't get updated till the next control gets focus.

The functionality works as expected in Chrome. This is strictly an IE 11/Windows problem. Is there something I need to to do tell it to work properly in IE 11?

Here is the code from one of my dropdowns.

```
<label>Workgroup</label>
<select class="form-control" style="width: 125px" data-ng-model="params.workgroupId" data-ng-options="w.id as w.name for w in workgroups"></select>
```

Comment: I don't know where problem is, but please follow steps in this article, to improve ie compability: [Internet Explorer Compatibility](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)

Comment: Thanks S.Panfilov. This didn't fix the problem, but I'm definitely missing this in my app and it alerted me to the fact that I might be using libraries that aren't compatible with all versions of IE. Going to start the app over and focus on IE compatibility this time.